# Grunt, how to minify different folders (to include node_modules folder)

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

I am using NPM in a WP project.

I already have a grunt task that compiles my separate SCSS files into CSS files and then minifies them into one `default.min.css` file when running `grunt` (that's good.)

My main issue is that I would like to include different npm packages such as fontawesome, bootstrap etc. where they also would be minified into that one minified min.css file, together with my own files.

I would also like to know how to do this for my own `*.js` files uglify'd with different packages i'm using (jquery-ui, owl-carousel, etc.)

Please find below my **Gruntfile.js**, this is my first Gruntfile.js so feel free to include any constructive remarks.

Thanks,
Bud

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'resource/scss/',
                    src: ['*.scss'],
                    dest: 'resource/builds/css/',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass', 'cssmin']
            },
            scripts: {
                files: 'resource/js/*.js',
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            target: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'resource/builds/css/',
                    src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                    dest: 'public/css',
                    ext: '.min.css'
                }]
            }
        },
        concat: {
            js: {
                options: {
                    separator: ';'
                },
                src: 'resource/**/*.js',
                dest: '<%= paths.dest.js %>'
            }
            },
        uglify: {
            build: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'resource/js/',
                    src: '**/*.js',
                    dest: 'public/js',
                    ext: '.min.js'
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['cssmin', 'uglify', 'watch']);

};
```

Comment: I know there are actual Bootstrap packages available, but bear in mind that if you simply include the bootstrap at (say) the top of your SCSS file, it will get "sucked in" and compiled into the one file. Same with fontAwesome of course. I am unaware of the benefits (if any) of using the actual Bootstrap packages à la https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-include-bootstrap

Comment: I normally @import my other scss files to my main one as needed and they are all all collected and minified so they don't necessarily have to all be added to the Gruntfile too.

Comment: @mayersdesign - thanks, yet I like to keep my css seperate, and since bootstrap (and other packages) are in their respective `node_modules` directories, I would like to use the code itself to cherry pick 'em and minify them, same goes for uglify for js, please let me know if you can help with the code. thanks dude.